# how does hive create table using parquet and snappy

Tags: hive, parquet, snappy

I know the syntax for creating a table using parquet but I want to know what does this mean to create tables using parquet format and compressed by snappy and how does we do that ? please help me with an example syntax.

What is the advantage by using snappy compression ?

Answer (score 16):

```
CREATE TABLE emp(id int, name string, department string, salary float)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
STORED AS PARQUET TBLPROPERTIES ("parquet.compression"="SNAPPY");
```

Answer (score 0):

Snappy has a good tradeoff between compression and CPU. Enabling snappy in parquet files should only be a config of your utility class.

Answer (score 0):

create table info(name string , city string,distance int) row format delimited fields terminated by `<terminator>` lines terminated by `<terminator>` stored as PARQUET tblproperties('parquet.compress'='SNAPPY');